# com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed assistive access - cannot click when running a quick action

Tags: applescript

I have a Quick Action that runs an AppleScript program which needs to click a button. However, when it gets to the clicking stage, it displays an error message:

> com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed assistive access

I've tried to give it permissions under System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Full Disk Access, but it only lets me add applications to the list, whereas this is a Quick Action (service).

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
         click button "End" of window 1
   end tell
end tell
```

It should have just clicked the button, but returned the error message as given above.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? Is  there a way for me to give com.automator.runner.xpc full disk access?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with automator services that have AppleScript actions in them. I suppose Gatekeeper doesn't like them because it looks like code injection.

The workaround (until Apple does something to fix the problem) is to take the AppleScript in your action and turn it into a stand-alone AppleScript application: copy the code into Script Editor and save the file, choosing **Application** from the *File Format* menu. Add this script app to the Accessibility Security pane — System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Privacy->Accessibility — and it should pass GateKeeper's muster. Then you have a choice, depending on your setup:

1. Create a Quick Action in Automator that calls the app.

Create a Quick Action as normal, and use the Launch Application action to run the script app. This should work as a service or as a Quick Action in the Finder preview pane

2. Turn the script app into a service in its own right.

In the Finder, find the script app, then select "Show Package Contents" from the contextual menu. Drill down to the file "info.plist", open it in a plain-text editor and edit in a new key-value unit that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    [...]
    <key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSBackgroundColorName</key>
            <string>background</string>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Service Name</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>run</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

... making sure not to delete or damage any of the default xml that Script Editor generates for script apps. Save the revised info.plist file, place the script app in ~/Library/Services. This only seems to work as a service (I can't get them to show up in the Extensions preference pane).

Comment: It’s not a Gatekeeper issue, it’s a sandbox issue. (GK prevents unapproved launching of newly downloaded executables; sandbox mediates executables access to external resources.) One limitation of Apple’s current sandboxing architecture is that it only applies at the GUI Application level; there’s no way to custom-sandbox a non-GUI process such as a scripting language interpreter running a particular user script. Fingers crossed this’ll be addressed by the time Shortcuts ships in 10.16; until then, as you say, the workaround is to save the script as an .app with its own unique bundle ID.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it into an application, gave the application permissions, and created a quick action that called it, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When I simply disconnected my external monitor today I noticed that the script that I was using that triggered this alert started working. So I believe it is directly related to that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).