# Quick Action permission under Catalina

Tags: macos, automator, macos-catalina

I made a Quick Action in Automator using Watch Me. When I try to execute it from the Services menu I get the message "this application must be allowed to control this computer..."

In the System Pref Accessibility I dragged in the saved Workflow and granted permission, but that made no difference. Automator is already in there and the Action works as expected when executed within it.

How do I properly grant the permission?

Catalina 10.15.4 Beta.

Comment: If the service contains a script, see if [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57349831/10853463) helps.

Comment: thanks. That topic is discouraging. It's just a "watch me" recording, but that might also apply.

Comment: Yes - the `Watch Me Do` action definitely uses accessibility (you can copy    its events to the Script Editor to see what they are).